# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'

Tags: android

Android Studio is showing this error. Can't find out what's causing the error.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:_internal_aapt2_binary'.
   > Could not download aapt2-windows.jar (com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.6.2-6040484): No cached version available for offline mode

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with downloading dependency:
`Could not download aapt2-windows.jar (com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.6.2-6040484): No cached version available for offline mode`.
It means that the dependency can't be downloaded because you're in offline mode or you don't have an Internet connection. Try to turn Gradle's **offline mode** off, check the **Internet connection** and try to build again.